# How can I get the "Google Response" to a query in the terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, utilities, google

I want to be able to get this terse result Google returns for some queries, from the command line:

[image]

I tried Googler, but it returns this:

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397) unless you really, really need to do so.

Comment: Does not directly answer the question, but you don't need the internet for this: `year=2018; for mon in {1..12}; do date -d "$year-$mon-1 + 1 month - 1 day" "+%B - %d days"; done` -- and then try it with `year=2020`

Answer (score -1):

this text and the site below and just look right you will see that it is not google! so do not find the "googler"

so you have the result that you that by the shell

install lynx first "apt install lynx"

lynx -dump https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/time/months-of-year.html | head -26 | tail -14

Comment: I am not dumb. Don't post an answer for the sake of posting an answer.

Comment: I did not mean to insult you!  and yes in you help! more ok then